# Prove that $\mathscr{A}(\alpha)+\mathscr{B}^*(\beta)=\xi$, $\mathscr{B}(\alpha)=\eta$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $\mathcal{L}$ is an $n$-dimensional real Euclid space with inner product $(*,\,*)_1$; $\mathcal{M}$ is an $m$-dimensional real Euclid space with inner product $(*,\,*)_2$. $\mathscr{A}$ is a linear transformation on $\mathcal{L}$; $\mathscr{B}$ is a linear map from $\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathcal{M}$. Let $\pi$ be an orthogonal projection from $\mathcal{L}$ into (not necessarily onto) $\ker(\mathscr{B})$ such that $\pi\circ\mathscr{A}\big|_{\ker(\mathscr B)}$ is a linear isomorphism. Furthermore, there is a constant $\lambda_0>0$ such that
> $$
> \inf_{0\ne\beta\in\mathcal{M}}\;\;\sup_{0\ne\alpha\in\mathcal{L}}\frac{|(\beta,\,\mathscr{B}(\alpha))_2|}{|\alpha|_1|\beta|_2}\geq\lambda_0. \tag{1}
> $$
> Show that for all $\xi\in\mathcal L$ and $\eta\in\mathcal M$, there exists a unique $\alpha\in\mathcal{L}$, $\beta\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathscr{A}(\alpha) + \mathscr{B}^*(\beta)=\xi$, $\mathscr{B}(\alpha)=\eta$, where $(\mathscr{B}^*(\beta),\,\alpha)_1 = (\beta,\,\mathscr{B}(\alpha))_2$.

From the inequality $(1)$, I observed that $\mathscr{B}$ must be surjective.

Also, the prove the uniqueness, we should prove that if $\alpha_1$, $\beta_1$ and $\alpha_2$, $\beta_2$ both satisfy the conclusion, then it must be that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1=\beta_2$.
Since $\alpha_2-\alpha_1\in\ker(\mathscr{B})$, and $\pi\circ\mathscr{A}\big|_{\ker(\mathscr B)}$ is an isomorphism, to prove $\alpha_2=\alpha_1$ it suffices to prove that $\pi\circ\mathscr{A}(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)=0$.

What I have got are listed above.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality (1) not only implies surjectivity for $\mathscr{B}$ but also implies $\mathscr{B}$ is a bijection from $\ker(B)^{\perp}$ to $\mathcal{M}$  because from this *inf-sup condition* we get
\begin{align}
\;\sup_{0\ne\alpha\in\mathcal{L}}\frac{|(\beta,\,\mathscr{B}(\alpha))_2|}{|\alpha|_1}
\sup_{0\ne\alpha\in\mathcal{L}}\frac{|(\mathscr{B}^{*}(\beta),\,\alpha)_1|}{|\alpha|_1}\geq\lambda_0 |\beta|_2 \quad \forall \beta \in \mathcal{M}. 
\end{align}
In other words $|\mathscr{B}^{*}(\beta)|_1\geq \lambda_0|\beta|_2$. Now this inequality implies $\mathscr{B}^{*}$ is inyective and has closed range. Then $R(\mathscr{B}^{*})=\ker((\mathscr{B}^{*})^{*})^{\perp}=\ker \mathscr{B}^{\perp}$.
Hence, $\mathscr{B}^{*}:\mathcal{M} \to \ker \mathscr{B}^{\perp} $ is a linear isomorphism. Also $R(\mathscr{B})=\ker(\mathscr{B}^{*})^{\perp}=\{0\}^{\perp}=\mathcal{M}$. Then $\mathscr{B}:\ker{\mathscr{B}}^{\perp}\to\mathcal{M}$ is a linear isomorfism. Hence, there is only one $\alpha \in \ker{\mathscr{B}}^{\perp}$ with
\begin{align}
\mathscr{B}(\alpha) = \eta \tag{1}
\end{align}
$\pi\circ\mathscr{A}:\ker{\mathscr{B}} \to \ker{\mathscr{B}}$ is a bijection. Hence, exist $\alpha_0 \in \ker{\mathscr{B}}$, such that, $\pi\circ\mathscr{A}(\alpha_0)=\pi(\xi-\mathscr{A}(\alpha))$.
Then $\mathscr{A}(\alpha_0+\alpha)- \xi \in \ker{\mathscr{B}}^{\perp}$, now exist a unique $\beta \in \mathcal{M}$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{B}^{*}(\beta)=\xi-\mathscr{A}(\alpha_0+\alpha) \tag{2}
\end{align}
Now note $(\alpha+\alpha_0,\beta)\in \mathcal{L}\times \mathcal{M}$, solves (1) and (2). Hence, the problem has solution.
Now for the uniqueness let $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ and $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ two solutions in $\mathcal{L}\times \mathcal{M}$, doing some calculations we get
\begin{align}
\mathscr{A}(\alpha_1-\alpha_0)+\mathscr{B}^{*}(\beta_1-\beta_0) &= 0 \tag{3}\\
\mathscr{B}(\alpha_1-\alpha_0) &= 0   \tag{4}
\end{align}
Note $\mathscr{B}^{*}(\beta_1-\beta_0) \in \ker \mathscr{B}^{\perp}$. Appliying $\pi$ on (3), we get $\pi\circ \mathscr{A}(\alpha_1-\alpha_0)=0$, so $\alpha_1=\alpha_0$. Finally because $\mathscr{B}^{*}:\mathcal{M} \to \ker \mathscr{B}^{\perp} $ is a bijection and $\mathscr{B}^{*}(\beta_1-\beta_0)=0$ we get $\beta_1=\beta_2$.
Note: This theorem is well-know as *Babuska-Brezzi Theorem*, see [1] for example of applications of this result.

[1] GATICA, Gabriel N. A simple introduction to the mixed finite element method. Theory and Applications. Springer Briefs in Mathematics. Springer, London, 2014.